# HK2 Jersey. How to get bean from container?

Tags: jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a chain of Features. I would like to `bind` some beans inside `ConfigFeature` and then get them inside the `MongoDBFeature`. What methods should I use for that?

```
public final class IoCBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        ConfigFeature.configureIoC(this);
        MongoDBFeature.configureIoC(this);

    }
}
```

Put some bean here:

```
public class ConfigFeature {
    public static void configureIoC(AbstractBinder binder) {
        // ....
        binder.bind(configProvider).to(ConfigurationProvider.class).in(Singleton.class).named("configProvider");
    }
}
```

And I would like to get `configProvider` bean here:

```
public class MongoDBFeature {
    public static void configureIoC(AbstractBinder binder) {
        // ?? get configProvider here ??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bind your bean to the `ServiceLocator` as shown in below example.

Service

```
public class TestService{

}
```

Binder

```
public static TestBinder extends AbstractBinder{
     @Override
     protected void configure() {
         bind(new TestService()).to(TestService.class);
     }
}
```

Feature 1

```
public class Feature1 implements Feature{

    @Inject
    private ServiceLocator locator;

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(locator,new TestBinder());
        return true;
    }

}
```

Note that a `ServiceLocator` instance is injected to Feature1 and the `binder` is bound to this locator instance.

Feature 2

```
public class Feature2 implements Feature{

    @Inject
    private TestService testService;

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Application/ResourceConfig class

```
public class TestConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    register(Feature1.class);

    // Need to make sure Feature1 is registered before Feature2. 
    // Another option is to register Feature2 in configure() method of Feature1 class.
    register(Feature2.class);
}
```